# Нужна помощь в составлении регулярки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть необходимость создать поиск совпадений по строке.

Например:

```
str = 'Hello, world!';
search_q = 'llo worl';
```

Нужно чтобы регулярка проверила, есть ли такие совпадения в строке.

search_q может быть любым, например 'world Hello'

Но прим этом, если искать будем 'Hello world Test' - то ничего не найдем

Comment: Разбивайте по пробелу и ищите совпадение для каждого куска. PHP не знаю, но пока не вижу зачем тут регулярки

Comment: Думаю, что регуляркой будет эффективней сделать поиск

Comment: А я думаю что нет. Псевдокод: `parts = search_q.Split(); foreach (part in parts) if (!str.Contains(part)) return false; return true;`

Comment: Пример, который в "например" - есть совпадение или нет?

Comment: Регулярные выражения следует использовать тогда и только тогда, когда они действительно необходимы. В вашем случае вам по любому придется разбивать поисковую строку по словам, а после этого регулярка уже и не нужна

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, нужно искать соответствия в строке по частичному совпадению? Тогда нужно преобразовать строку `'llo worl'` в шаблон следующим образом:

```
$str = 'Hello, world!';
$search_q = 'llo worl';

$patt = strtr($search_q, [' ' => '\W+']);
preg_match("~\w*{$patt}\w*~i", $str, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

---

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello, world
)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ)